# How to test for overfitting in a TAR model in R?

Tags: r, autoregressive, overfitting, nonlinear

I want to fit a threshold autoregressive model, and I'm using the tar package in R. For ARIMA models, I could check if a model was overfit by looking at the values of standard errors as compared to estimates. If errors were much smaller, I would assume there is no overfit. However, I don't see a provision to check overfit in TAR model. There is no standard error, and so I wouldn't know where to stop fitting. I can check for residual whiteness to prevent underfitting, but how would I prevent high orders? When I check AIC, I find that the higher the order, the smaller the AIC. So that's not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my friend found out how to get the standard errors. In the tar function, set print = TRUE, and this will print out the standard error.